Compile Kotlin desktop application into single exe
I've got a Kotlin desktop application that I compile with Gradle into a self-containing distributable folder. However, that output folder contains 372 files making it difficult to publish so I zip it before sending it to other departments.
Apart from the dependencies, the main part of my build.gradle.kt looks like this:
compose.desktop {
    application {
        mainClass = "MainKt"
        javaHome = System.getenv("JDK_17")
        jvmArgs += listOf("-Xmx2G")
        nativeDistributions {
            targetFormats(TargetFormat.Exe)            
            packageVersion = "1.2.3"
            packageName = "MyApp-v$packageVersion"
            includeAllModules = true // include java runtime
            windows {
                perUserInstall = true
            }
        }

        buildTypes.release.proguard {
            isEnabled = false
        }
    }
}

Is there a way to compile this application into a single exe containing all the dependencies and the java runtime? I'd rather not use the MSI installer and prefer to be it portable if possible.
